# WP7 Stop page from Navigating/Going back

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I stop my application from going back when the user clicks on the "Cancel" button after hitting the back button?

```
      protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var buttonInfo = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        if (buttonInfo == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            this.NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
        else
        {
            //How to stop page from navigating
        }
    }
```

Comment: Be careful in doing this, as depending on the use, it might fall foul of the certification requirements; specifically [section 5.2.4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184840%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CancelEventArgs` to cancel the action, property [Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx).

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // If the event has already been cancelled, do nothing
    if(e.Cancel)
        return;

    var buttonInfo = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
    if (buttonInfo == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        this.NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
    else
    {
        //Stop page from navigating
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad it works for you. You should also check if the even has already been cancelled and do nothing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A little more ..

```
   protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancel)
            return;

        var buttonInfo = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        if (buttonInfo == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
          **//this line may useful if you are in the very first page of your app**
            if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack) 
            {
                this.NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Stop page from navigating
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```